# PHP mail function not sending HTML mail

Tags: php, email

Hello The Genious peoples....
I am trying to send a html mail using php everything in my php script looks to be correct but when  I send the mail I recieve only plain text.  This is the link url i am using to test the script http://www.mailme.netne.net
you may check it here..

These are the codes in script:

```
<?php 
require 'ErrorHandler.inc.php';  
//.....set up a boundary to seperate the message..........  
$boundary = '======'.md5(mt_rand(4,time())).'======';  
$headers=array();  
$headers[]='MIME-Version:1.0';  
$headers[]='Content-type:multipart/alternative;boundary="'.$boundary.'"'; 
$headers[]='From: '.$_POST['from'];  
$msg_body = 'This a is Multipart Message in MIME Format'."\n";  
$msg_body .= '--'.$boundary."\n";  
$msg_body .= 'Content-Type:text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"'."\n"; 
$msg_body .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding:7bit'."\n\n";  
$msg_body .=$_POST['message'] ."\n"; 
$msg_body .= '--'.$boundary."\n"; 
$msg_body .= 'Content-Type:text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"'."\n";
$msg_body .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding:7bit'."\n\n";  
$msg_body .=strip_tags($_POST['message']) . "\n";  
$msg_body .= '--'.$boundary.'--'."\n";  
//======================send n test return value=======================
$success  = mail($_POST['to'],$_POST['sub'],$msg_body,implode("\r\n",$headers)) ;
if($success)  
{ echo "<strong>Your mail sent </strong>";}    
else     
{echo "<strong>Error Sending your mail..please try again later</strong>";}  
echo " with following details:<br /><br />";  
echo "<strong>From : </strong><em>" .$_POST['from']."<br />";  
echo "<strong>To&nbsp;&nbsp;: </strong><em>".$_POST['to'].  "<br/>";  
echo "<strong>Subject : </strong><em>".$_POST['sub']."<br />";  
echo "<strong>Message : </strong><em>".$msg_body."<br />";  
 ?>
```

please help me ..I am trying since last 6 days..

Comment: You might want to use http://swiftmailer.org/ instead of writing your own.

Comment: It's not an answer to your problem, but you really should think again about a script that sends user-entered text to a user-entered email address. As it is, it's wide open to abuse by spammers.

Comment: There are many libraries available for constructing emails for you, like PHPMailer.  You'd be better off using one of them instead of trying to concat an email together ad-hoc.

Comment: try phpmailer its very cool and easy ,effective

Answer (score 1):

You're adding header data to your message body:

```
$msg_body .= 'Content-Type:text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"'."\n"; 
$msg_body .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding:7bit'."\n\n";
```

But you're not actually adding it to your headers like so:

```
$headers[] = 'Content-Type:text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"';
$headers[] = 'Content-Transfer-Encoding:7bit';
```

Try this:

```
<?php 
require 'ErrorHandler.inc.php'; 

//.....set up a boundary to seperate the message..........  
$boundary = '======'.md5(mt_rand(4,time())).'======';  

$headers    =   array();  
$headers[]  =   'MIME-Version:1.0';  
$headers[]  =   'Content-type:multipart/alternative;boundary="'.$boundary.'"'; 
$headers[]  =   'From: '.$_POST['from']; 
$headers[]  =   'Content-Type:text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"';
$headers[]  =   'Content-Transfer-Encoding:7bit';

$msg_body = 'This a is Multipart Message in MIME Format'."\n";  
$msg_body .= '--'.$boundary."\n";  
$msg_body .= 'Content-Type:text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"'."\n"; 
$msg_body .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding:7bit'."\n\n";  
$msg_body .=$_POST['message'] ."\n"; 
$msg_body .= '--'.$boundary."\n"; 
$msg_body .= 'Content-Type:text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"'."\n";
$msg_body .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding:7bit'."\n\n";  
$msg_body .=strip_tags($_POST['message']) . "\n";  
$msg_body .= '--'.$boundary.'--'."\n";  


//======================send n test return value=======================
$success  = mail($_POST['to'],$_POST['sub'],$msg_body,implode("\r\n",$headers)) ;
if($success){ 
    echo "<strong>Your mail sent </strong>";
}    
else     
{
    echo "<strong>Error Sending your mail..please try again later</strong>";    
}  

echo " with following details:<br /><br />";  
echo "<strong>From : </strong><em>" .$_POST['from']."<br />";  
echo "<strong>To&nbsp;&nbsp;: </strong><em>".$_POST['to'].  "<br/>";  
echo "<strong>Subject : </strong><em>".$_POST['sub']."<br />";  
echo "<strong>Message : </strong><em>".$msg_body."<br />";
?>
```

Comment: thanks for taking INterst,  but what will this do..  this way we are just adding the content -type declaration twice once in header and again in msg_body.